# ReduceByKey for a HashMap based RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a **RDD A** of the form tuple `(key,HashMap[Int, Set(String)])` which I want to convert to a new  **RDD B** `(key, HashMap[Int, Set(String))` where the latter RDD has unique keys and the value for each key **k** is **union** of all sets for key **k** in **RDD A**.

For example,

**RDD A**

```
(1,{1->Set(3,5)}), (2,{3->Set(5,6)}), (1,{1->Set(3,4), 7->Set(10, 11)})
```

will convert to

**RDD B**

```
(1, {1->Set(3,4,5), 7->Set(10,11)}), (2, {3->Set(5,6)})
```

I am not able to formulate a function for this in Scala as I am new to the language. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`cats` `Semigroup` would be a great fit here. Add

```
spark.jars.packages org.typelevel:cats_2.11:0.9.0
```

to the configuration and use `combine` method:

```
import cats.implicits._

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, Map(1 -> Set(3,5))),
  (2, Map(3 -> Set(5,6))),
  (1, Map(1 -> Set(3,4), 7 -> Set(10, 11)))

rdd.reduceByKey(_ combine _)
```